# Offline Gradle Build Failure

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, offline-mode

I don't have stable internet connection in my area so I think of using the offline component found on Android studio download page namely `Android Gradle Plugin` and `Google Maven dependencies` I followed the offline component set instructions on this page https://developer.android.com/r/studio-offline/instructions
But after all the set up if I open Android studio and click on a sample project I use to have a build sync error pointing to the  `manual-offline-m2` . I need help in this area .

NB: if I connect to the internet and open a new sample project in Android studio without those offline set up it will build successfully. [![Screenshot of the build sync failure.][2]][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoddD.jpg[image][image]

Comment: there are many components in android Gradle which need an internet connection to build that's why it often fail

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio require a Internet connection because when you open new project, Android Studio is reinstalling Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

The image you have provided is not clear. However, Gradle build can run without an internet connection. You have to enable offline-mode from settings. (**Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle** & check **Offline work** checkbox) Then Gradle will avoid using network resources. But sometimes it may cause errors, at that time you may want an internet connection.

**EDIT:**

To enable offline work in Android Studio 3.6+ go to **View > Tool Windows > Gradle** from the menu bar & open the Gradle window. Then click **Toggle Offline Mode** button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have included a clear picture .... But to that path you specify (Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle)  .... But there is no offline work checkbox there ... Am using Android Studio 4.0